# Does setState() trigger itself when variables and data change just like stream and streambuilder does?

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

```
class _LocationScreenState extends State<LocationScreen> {
WeatherModel weather = WeatherModel();


String weatherMessage;
String weatherIcon;
String cityName;
int temperature;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
updateUI(widget.locationWeather);
}

void updateUI(dynamic weatherData) {
setState(() {
temperature=weatherData['main']['temp'].toInt();
var condition = weatherData['weather'][0]['id'];

cityName=weatherData['name'];
weatherIcon=weather.getWeatherIcon(condition);
weatherMessage=weather.getMessage(temperature);
});

}
```

Hi I am getting confused with what setState() does. If the value of temperature or condition or anything changes inside that of setState does setState() trigger itself to update the UI and build UI with updated temp or condition or do I have to invoke updateUI function myself to invoke setState and update the UI?

Answer (score 0):

SetState Rebuild the build method whenever it called.

SetState never call it self, you have to call it. If you change value of your variable and did not use SetState then it will not reflect in UI, to do so you have to call SetState.

As you put you code in updateUI in SetState, so it will update ui whenever you call that method, where as if you don't use SetState there then it will not reflect changes in UI.

Comment: So streamBuilder will help? Because for now if I want to reflect changes in UI with changing temp and condition, I have to hot restart.

Comment: no, You can call SetState whenever you change value of variable as you are doing in updateUI method.

Answer (score 0):

documentation states that `setState(fn())`, Calling setState notifies the framework that the internal state of this object has changed in a way that might impact the user interface in this subtree, which causes the framework to schedule a build for this State object.

whenever a setState called the ui will be scheduled for a build based on the new state.

Eg:

```
 class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  String text;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    text = "Hello";
  }

  void updateUI(String action) {
    setState(() {
      text = action;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      Text(text, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
      MaterialButton(
          onPressed: () {
            updateUI("Pressed");
          },
          child: Text("Change state"))
    ]);
  }
}
```

Note : `initState()` will be called once in the life cycle of Stateful widget.

Answer (score 0):

**setState():**

Notify the framework that the internal state of this object has changed.

Whenever you change the internal state of a State object, make the change in a function that you pass to setState:

```
setState(() { _myState = newValue; });
```

Calling setState notifies the framework that the internal state of this object has changed in a way that might impact the user interface in this subtree, which causes the framework to schedule a build for this State object.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you need to call it in order to "re-draw" the current stateful widget. I believe the variable that changed doesn't need to be wrapped inside the setState either, as long as it's changed before the setState.